# Android unable to download APK from end-point signed by NetworkSolutions DV CA

Tags: android, ssl

I have an nginx serving an .apk file. For my domain name, the nginx is configured to serve a SSL certificate signed by Network Solutions DV Server 2 CA which is in turned signed by AddTrust External CA Root. I'm **able to**

1. download the apk file from desktop (Chrome/macOS or curl/macOS) via **https** in 4 minutes
2. download it over **http** in Android 4.x and 5.1
3. verify that the http response has `Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive`
4. access the index page of my domain over **https** without seeing certificate warnings on Android 5.1 (on Android 4, it would warn untrusted CA despite both versions having AddTrust CA as a root CA.)
5. download fully a similar sized JPG photo in the android browser over **https** from my server
6. if I host the apk in S3, Android is able to download it using **https**

However, I'm **not able to**

1. download the apk from my server with **https** in Android 4 or 5, the download is queued in download center and eventually failed (I saw that it would transiently switch to In Progress state and then back to Queued state quickly.)
2. or download from my server over **https** when it is served directly by nginx (without proxying to tomcat)

Repeating the download many times still won't work.

While the SSL issue may cause it to fail on Android 4, I would expect it to go through in Android 5 at least. What would cause Android download center to fail?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Android Download Center has a different SSL verification than the browser. The intermediate CA certificate is built in in the Android 5 browser but not in the Download Center or Android 4 browser. After [configuring nginx to present full certificate chain](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains), the APK download works and also the Android 4 browser also will not show untrusted CA warning.